# Access Virtual WAMP Server on Local Network

Tags: windows, wamp, virtual-machine, wampserver

I have a server on which there is a virtual machine running WAMP Server. I can access the "site" aka the wampserver on the  physics server outside the virtual machine. However I want to access it from another PC on the same network as the physical server.

Virtual machines ip is: 192.168.189.128

The physical servers ip is: 172.16.0.164

Comment: What is the ip address of the other PC on the network that you want to get access from

Comment: @RiggsFolly 172.16.0.241

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Edit: your httpd.conf file ( use the menus to get to the correct file )
```

Look for this

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
```

Add a new line AFTER

```
    Allow from ......
```

Like this

```
    Allow from 172.16.0.241
```

Or if you want to be able to see the wampserver from the whole subnet

```
    Allow from 172.16.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple configuration changes to enable wamp access through LAN

`C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\httpd.conf`

Include "Allow from all" at each line no : 243, 281, 393, and if you found any "Deny" word replace it by "Allow" and include "Allow from all" below "Allow from 127.0.0.1"

If you found

`C:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf`
replace "Deny from all" by "Allow from all"

Restart your wamp and put online by clicking in tray icon then surely it will work.